# Multiprocessing HTTP get requests with a Tornado/Python3 API Service

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, tornado

I build two different Tornado/Python3 API services.

Service1 opens several different threads and semi-parallel sends a GET request to Service2.
However, Service2 (Tornado/Python3) then proceeds to sequentially process the GET request.

Code example of Service2:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
                self.write("Some Microservice v1")


def make_app():
        return tornado.web.Application([
                (r"/v1", MainHandler),
                (r"/v1/addfile", AddHandler, dict(filepaths = filepaths)),
                (r"/v1/getfiles", GetHandler, dict(filepaths = filepaths)),
                (r"/v1/getfile", GetFileHandler, dict(filepaths = filepaths)),
                ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = make_app()
        app.listen(8887, address='127.0.0.1')
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

I have tried to manually fork processes, to achieve better performance, but this did not work.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        #app = make_app()
        #app.listen(8887, address='127.0.0.1')
        #tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
        sockets = tornado.netutil.bind_sockets(8887)
        tornado.process.fork_processes(8)
        server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
        server.add_sockets(sockets)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

What am I missing here? Do I actually need to go into each Handler class and define coroutines and callbacks?

Greatful for help,

Thank you.

Comment: ref https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html

Answer (score 0):

Working as intended. My Service1 was using up all my cores on the test environment, that is why there were no cores left for Service2.